# Although If Controller JMeterThread.last_sample_ok = false, why is child HTTP Request not skipped with Evaluate for all children

Tags: jmeter

[image: JMeter Test Plan and Response]

With `OpenSubmission failing on assertion` and `JMeterThread.last_sample_ok=false`, why is child to If **Controller** (HTTP request PostDocument) executing?

Comment: are they real tests?

Answer (score 2):

Because you have the [Debug Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Debug_Sampler) between failing sampler and the If Controller. Debug Sampler is successful in the absolute majority of cases, and it generates a result and overwrites `${JMeterThread.last_sample_ok}` variable.

So

1. Disable or remove the Debug Sampler which is before the If Controller. If you need debugging information - consider adding [Debug PostProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Debug_PostProcessor) as  child of the "OpenSubmission" request
2. Make sure you use `${JMeterThread.last_sample_ok}` as If Controller condition.

Demo:

[image: Debug Sampler Overwrite last result]

See [How to Use JMeter's 'IF' Controller and Get Pie](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeters-if-controller-and-get-pie) guide for comprehensive information on conditionally executing JMeter Samplers using If Controller.